# Is there a waiting period prior to applying for a Tier 2 Dependant Visa?

Tags: working-visas, immigration

I'm going to start working for the NHS before the year ends. My CoS doesn't cover my dependant (husband). I asked my agency (home based) about applying for the Dependant Visa (after I've read about it in the UKVI website) just to confirm, and they said I need to wait 3 months before I can go ahead and apply. For a second opinion, I asked my UK based agency about it, too. They said I need to wait 6 months before I can apply. Now I know from the UKVI website that this isn't true because I can apply with my dependant at the same time. Question is, if I missed something in the numerous guides in the UKVI. Does anyone know about a 3-6 month rule before applying for a dependant? I've insisted to both my agencies that the wait isn't necessary and they'd just answer with a "No, you'll have to wait." and I don't want to waste time because if I can apply with my husband for both our visas at the same time, why would we wait for 3 months?

Another question is, do we have to provide accommodation requirements? My friend is residing in the UK and she's offered to take us in until we find an apartment. Thing is, she's in a flat share. She'll rent out one of the rooms for us to stay in until we are able to find suitable accommodation. Would a letter from her suffice for the dependant visa application  in terms of proving that we've got the accommodation covered?

Do we need to provide relationship proof, too? We've been married for 8months, and we've been together 3 years before that.

Comment: Based on comments on UK visitor visas, I think your friend would have to have permission from the owner that she can sub-lease/rent the room to you.

Answer (score 1):

Your husband can apply at the same time as you do, or separately. However, you will have an added burden of proof, as your Tier 2 Certificate of Sponsorship does not include your husband. And, should it specifically excludes him, you may have to delay application until you are able to establish your own financial and accommodation guarantees.

The  [Guidance for dependants of UK visa applicants (Tiers 1, 2, 4, 5)](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/603815/PBS_dependent_guidance_Jan_2017.pdf) outlines in full what is needed (pages 13-14):

> **Family member of a Tier 2 Migrant**
>
> 61. You must have £630 to support yourself.
> 62. This requirement can be met by:
>
>     - having savings of £630 which must have been held for at least three months prior to the date of application; or
>     - the Tier 2 A-rated sponsor providing a written undertaking that, should it become necessary, it will maintain and accommodate the family member for a month. The undertaking may be limited 14 provided the limit is at least £630 per family member. A Tier 2 A-rated sponsor can do this by:
>
> a) endorsing the certification on the Certificate of Sponsorship, or
>   b) providing the certification in a letter from the sponsor which includes:
>
> i. the applicant’s name, 
>   ii. the sponsor’s name and logo, and 
>   iii. details of any limit
>
> 63. For example, the Tier 2 Migrant is making an application at the same time as their spouse and two children. They must show that they have £630 for their spouse and a further £630 for each child, in addition to £945 required for their own support. In total the family will require evidence that they hold £2835 in available funds (£630 x 3 = £1890 + £945).
> 64. If you apply at the same time as the main applicant, you are only required to provide evidence that you meet the maintenance requirement when the Tier 2 Migrant is also required to meet the maintenance requirement.
> 65. If you apply separately from the main applicant you will need to have the necessary funds to meet the maintenance requirement or have a written undertaking from an A-rated Sponsor, unless the main applicant already had leave in a Tier 2 category and when applying for their most recent period of Tier 2 leave was not required to show evidence of satisfying maintenance requirements.

Beginning on age 16, also look at **Evidence for applications made as the dependant of a person with leave under Tier 1, 2 or 5**